# Problema con script para actualizar indexeddb, item de la db no modifica

Tags: javascript, reactjs, update, indexeddb

Todo parece indicar que la data conecta bien hasta:

```
..........
...
...
       openRequest = indexedDB.open(a.db, a.ver)
       openRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
            var db = e.target.result
            var transaction = db.transaction(a.db, 'readwrite')
            const store = transaction.objectStore(a.db)
            var index = store.index('Id')
                            
            console.log(index)
```

Imprimí el objeto index lo que me confirma que hasta aqui al parecer funciona bien:

```
var keyRange = IDBKeyRange.only(523)
                index.openCursor(keyRange).onsucess = function (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                    var cursor = e.target.result;
                    console.log(cursor)
                    if (cursor) {
                        var item = cursor.value;
                        console.log(item)
                    }
                };
```

Mi problema radica en que no puedo modificar el `item 523` almacenado en el indexeddb, estoy omitiendo algo?, ... necesito modificarlo, ayuda porfavor.

**Editado: Mastes 09 de Novienbre 2021**

luego de revisar la documentacion encontre una forma diferente de hacerlo.

```
 var index = transaction.index('Id')
        const objidbc2 = index.get(523);
        objidbc2.onsuccess = () => {
           // salvo el resultado en data
           const data = objidbc2.result;
        
           //realize mis cambios                
           data.State = 3
           data.Endd = dateFormat(new Date(), 'isoDateTime')
           //dateFormtat es una dependencia que ayuda mucho cuando de fortmatos de tiempo se trata

           //envio el objeto con lo cambios de vuelta
           transaction.put(data).onsuccess = (e) => {
           console.log(e)
           //se puegre agregas mas eventos despues de...
        }
```

Comment: Si pudieras re-formular la pregunta, no esta claro el objetivo. ¿Intentas hacer una operación update al item 523 de indexeddb y no funciona? saludos